# sql query + limit + count overall results in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT topics.*
FROM topics topics
    JOIN rh_topictags tt ON tt.topic_id = topics.topic_id
    JOIN rh_topictags_tag t ON tt.tag_id = t.id
    JOIN forums f ON f.forum_id = topics.forum_id
WHERE LOWER(t.tag) IN ('super', 'fun')
    AND f.rh_topictags_enabled = 1
    AND topics.forum_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
    AND topics.topic_visibility = 1
GROUP BY topics.topic_id
HAVING count(t.id) = 2
ORDER BY topics.topic_last_post_time DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

How can I get the count of the overall found rows (without the limit)?

I can **not** use `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` as this query must run under several DBMS (mysql, mssql, oracle, postgres, sqlite, sqlite3).

Unfortunatly this does not work:

```
SELECT topics.*, COUNT(topics.*) AS result_count
FROM topics topics
    JOIN rh_topictags tt ON tt.topic_id = topics.topic_id
    JOIN rh_topictags_tag t ON tt.tag_id = t.id
    JOIN forums f ON f.forum_id = topics.forum_id
WHERE LOWER(t.tag) IN ('super', 'fun')
    AND f.rh_topictags_enabled = 1
    AND topics.forum_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
    AND topics.topic_visibility = 1
GROUP BY topics.topic_id
HAVING count(t.id) = 2
ORDER BY topics.topic_last_post_time DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: You will need to join a select query where you do the count without the limit

Comment: But then I have this huge query within the SELECT part of the outer query? Then I better run two queries...

Comment: Yes you probably should run two if you need to limit the results.. even though its technically possible to do it in one..

Comment: ok, but how? removing topics.* and adding COUNT(topics.*) as result_count does not work :(

Comment: Count(topics.*) is invalid syntax.. You can just do * or topics.topic_id

Comment: count(topics.topic_id) as well as count(*) does not work because of group_by / having

Comment: If you want help you need to post relevant data preferrably a sql fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
Select * 
from
( 
    SELECT topics.*, count(*) as result_count
    FROM topics topics
        JOIN rh_topictags tt ON tt.topic_id = topics.topic_id
        JOIN rh_topictags_tag t ON tt.tag_id = t.id
        JOIN forums f ON f.forum_id = topics.forum_id
    WHERE LOWER(t.tag) IN ('super', 'fun')
        AND f.rh_topictags_enabled = 1
        AND topics.forum_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
        AND topics.topic_visibility = 1
    GROUP BY topics.topic_id
    HAVING count(t.id) = 2
) a
ORDER BY a.topic_last_post_time DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: this gives me 4 results with each having result_count = 1 (should be 4 as there are 4 results)

Comment: so if you run only the inner query are you getting the `result_count = 4 `? And is 4 the full count - it's not quote clear from the question..?

Comment: ok I solved it with this approach and then doing two queries! Thank you for the hint: SELECT COUNT(*) as total_results FROM (SELECT topics.* FROM phpbb_topics topics JOIN... HAVING count(t.id) = 2) a